# How to draw compositions of multiple fields that have the same class type?

Tags: c#, class, uml, associations, multiplicity

I’m sorry if the title is not clear enough. FYI, I’m trying to make an UML diagram from a class. Here’s a snippet of the class:

```
class ItemDisplay {
    Item currentItem;
    Item[] suggestedItems;
    Item[] randomlySelectedItems;
}
```

How do I have to draw the associations of this class? Should I draw 3 separate associations with the same classes or just one but many multiplicities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should draw three associations.

Multiplicities is for one member to define a collection (array, list...).

So here you have two with multiplicity `0..*`.

Here are some tutorials:

[UML association multiplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650657/uml-association-multiplicity)

[UML Class Relationships](https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/class-diagram-relationships/)

[UML Association vs Aggregation vs Composition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/)

[UML Class Diagrams Reference](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-reference.html)

[UML Class Diagrams: Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/modeling/uml-class-diagrams-guidelines?view=vs-2015)

[Defining Classes and Class Relationships](http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/csharp2/csharp210.html)

[UML Tutotrial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/index.htm)

[The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual](https://books.google.fr/books?id=T7c3RwAACAAJ)

Comment: Got it. I was confused since all the sources and tutorials that I’ve read doesn’t have any example on when there are multiple associations like the one I’ve quoted here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated the answer with some links. I hope they will help you. Have a good reading.